# How to limit transfer speed of file within the same file shared network in python

Tags: python, file, networking, sleep, file-transfer

I would want to transfer file(copy) within a same shared network within 5mbps
using the method below im unable tot get 5mbps consistently it give me for example 12mpbs, 10mpbs then drop to 0mbps later on

```
def copy_file_with_bandwidth(source_path, target_path, bandwidth):
    # Convert bandwidth from Mbps to bytes per second
    bandwidth_bytes = bandwidth * 1024 * 1024 // 8 

    with open(source_path, "rb") as source_file:
        with open(target_path, "wb") as target_file:
            start_time = time.time()
            while True:
                data = source_file.read(bandwidth_bytes)
                if not data: #data empty get out loop
                    break
                target_file.write(data)
                target_file.flush()  # Ensure data is written to disk immediately

                # Delay to maintain the desired bandwidth
                elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
                expected_time = elapsed_time + (len(data) / bandwidth_bytes)
                if expected_time > elapsed_time:
                    time.sleep(expected_time - elapsed_time)

source_folder = "\\\\MYPESC0NBIT222\\Users\\1.bmp"
destination_folder = "C:\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\1.bmp"

copy_file_with_bandwidth(source_path, destination_folder , 5)
```

I am attempting to introduce a delay while writing a file to a different location. However, i try using a different approach using request.get() it doesnt work, as it is only functional for URLs. My desired outcome is to maintain a consistent transfer speed of 5 Mbps when copying the file within the same shared network, without experiencing spikes or drops. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why? Just let it happen at warp speed. The faster the transfer, the sooner it will be over and the available bandwidth restored, and anyway TCP shares bandwidth pretty efficiently.

Comment: @user207421 because i dont want it to take too much bandwidth for example if i have like maybe 20gb of file i would like take up all the bandwidth avaible and slow down the whole network for everyone else currently i still cant think of any other way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

What about reading at chunks of 5MB each and sleep every 1 second?

```
import time
import os


def copy_with_consistent_speed(source_path, destination_path, speed_limit_mbps):
    buffer_size = int(speed_limit_mbps * 1024 * 1024)  # Convert Mbps to bytes
    total_size = os.path.getsize(source_path)
    copied_size = 0

    start_time = time.time()

    with open(source_path, "rb") as source_file, open(
        destination_path, "wb"
    ) as dest_file:
        while True:
            chunk = source_file.read(buffer_size)
            if not chunk:
                break
            dest_file.write(chunk)
            copied_size += len(chunk)

            percent_complete = min(100, int(copied_size / total_size * 100))
            progress_mb = f"{copied_size / (1024 * 1024):.2f}"
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            speed_mbps = f"{(copied_size / (1024 * 1024)) / elapsed_time:.2f}"
            remaining_time = (
                int((total_size - copied_size) / (1024 * 1024 * float(speed_mbps)))
                if speed_mbps != "0.00"
                else 0
            )
            progress = f"{percent_complete}% ({progress_mb} MB / {total_size / (1024 * 1024):.2f} MB)"
            transfer_info = (
                f"Speed: {speed_mbps} Mbps, Remaining Time: {remaining_time} seconds"
            )
            print(f"Copying... {progress} {transfer_info}\r", end="")
            time.sleep(1)

    print(f"\nFile copied successfully to {destination_path}!")
```

To smooth out the transfer there is also much more complicated way to do it. Like the code above. You can define the buffer size and calculate the number of chunks necessary to send the entire file. Then you can calculate how much time you should sleep

```
import time
import os


def copy_file(source, destination, bandwidth, buffer_size):
    # Calculate the number of chunks to transfer
    file_size = os.path.getsize(source)
    num_chunks = file_size // buffer_size
    if file_size % buffer_size != 0:
        num_chunks += 1
    copied_bytes = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    # Open the source file for reading
    with open(source, "rb") as src_file:
        # Open the destination file for writing
        with open(destination, "wb") as dest_file:
            # Initialize variables for progress update
            transferred_chunks = 0
            prev_percentage = 0

            # Read and write the file in chunks
            while True:
                # Read a chunk of data from the source file
                chunk = src_file.read(buffer_size)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                copied_bytes += len(chunk)
                # Write the chunk to the destination file
                dest_file.write(chunk)
                elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
                speed_mbps = (copied_bytes / (1024 * 1024)) / elapsed_time
                # Update progress
                transferred_chunks += 1
                percentage = int(transferred_chunks / num_chunks * 100)
                remaining_time = (file_size - copied_bytes) / (
                    speed_mbps * (1024 * 1024)
                )
                print(file_size)
                if percentage > prev_percentage:
                    print(
                        f"\rProgress: {percentage}% ({copied_bytes/(1024 * 1024)}/{file_size/(1024 * 1024)} MB | Speed: {speed_mbps:.2f}Mbps | Remaining: {remaining_time:.2f} s)",
                        end="",
                    )
                    prev_percentage = percentage

                # Simulate the transfer speed delay
                time.sleep(buffer_size / (bandwidth * 1024 * 1024))  # 5 Mbps

    print("\nFile copy completed successfully.")


copy_file(
    r"D:\VM\Seven-2b4ec19b.vmem",
    r"D:\VM\test",
    5,
    512 * 1024,  # 512 KB
)
```

Comment: this doesnt really solve the issue if there large file for example the network throughtput will spike over 5mbps

Comment: both of the solutions?

Comment: yes both of it @marksoe